# How to debug hanging tramp connections?

Tags: tramp

With recent versions of Emacs, tramp routinely hangs at the time of making the connection.

The `*Messages*` buffer gives no information.

Is there a way to get more information as to what's happening?

---

I have seen this hanging behavior in two forms.

On `sudo`-based connections, tramp hangs right after I enter the password for `sudo`, and hit return.

On `ssh`-based connections, tramp will hang right after the appearance of the message

```
Waiting from prompts from remote shell...
```

In either case, it would be helpful to know what tramp is doing all this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the Tramp manual about traces `(info "(tramp) Traces and Profiles")`

In short, set `tramp-verbose` to 6, rerun your test, and check the Tramp debug buffer. In some rare cases it might be necessary to use a higher verbosity, up to 10.

If you have problems understanding the traces, contact the Tramp team by writing a bug report to `<tramp-devel@gnu.org>`.

Answer (score 7):

I had it hang because it couldn't detect the shell prompt, I added this to my .zshenv file..

```
# Fix for TRAMP
[ $TERM = "dumb" ] && unsetopt zle && PS1='$ '
```

Alternatively you can change what is considered a shell prompt by emacs..

```
; The default does not like the ~ before > so do a kludge
(setq shell-prompt-pattern '"^[^#$%>\n]*~?[#$%>] *")
```

(Mine is "[hostname] ~> ")

Comment: That fixed mine too. The default zsh shell prompt seems to break Tramp.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize this is how TRAMP works. So it stands to reason that some of these fancy Z shell prompts https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes#themes will also be incompatible with TRAMP, by default?

Comment: Yes, but if you modify the .zshenv as I did then the fancy prompt will be disabled for TRAMP (because the TERM type will be 'dumb' rather than, say, xterm)